# Multiple text file upload Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My app is currently set up to upload and parse a single file at a time:

Form in my View:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "#{controller}", :action => "import"}, :multipart => true) do %>
    <em>Upload a tab-separated .txt file.</em>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <br/>
    <%= submit_tag "Import Data", :class => "btn btn-link"%>
    <% end %>
```

My Controller:

```
  def import
    file = params[:file]
    RatingSet.generate_uploaded_rating_set({:conditions => "data_1", :file => file})
    redirect_to "/index", :flash => { :notice => "Successfully Uploaded." }
  end
```

I then parse and add the file contents in a method in my RatingSet model.

How can I upload multiple text files to different controllers? I would like the add about 4 form upload fields, and allow the user to choose which controller they would like to upload the form to. Ideally I would like to user JS to add new form fields, for as many forms the user would like to upload, however 4 fields would suffice for now.

Comment: why do you need to upload to 4 controllers, it's odd to have such an implement.

Comment: I second this, seems odd.  You could just use 4 different buttons on the same form, to the same controller, and then use something like `params[:submit]` to differentiate within the controller.

Comment: I have 4 different controllers for each of the different models to which data can be uploaded.